# Apache on VM is not reachable from LAN

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, vmware-fusion

I have a **CentOS** machine installed on **VMware Fusion** and connected to my LAN through a bridge connection. Everything works fine, I can

1. Surf on internet from the guest machine.
2. Ping other network machine from the guest.
3. Ping the guest machine from the host AND from the other machines on the Network.
4. Connect via SSH from the host to the guest AND from all the other machines in the network.

BUT the **Apache** server installed on the guest is **not reachable** from any machine. It answers just locally, typing 127.0.0.1 and also the guest network address.

I tried to solve:

`1. Checking the httpd.conf if it was listening on 80 and if external connection was allowed 
 2. Disabling the firewall`

And I'm absolutely sure that all the machines are on the same network.

But no changes. What's wrong?
Every kind of suggestion or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you please post the wireshark packet capture from the Apache machine?

Comment: At the moment I can't install wireshark, but i will as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dissable SELinux or, at least, put it on permissive mode.

You are looking at your config file, but you should be looking at:

```
netstat -punta | grep LISTEN
```

There is where reality lives. If your apache server is not listening there, make sure you edited the config file as it should be, restart the service and check again.

If still not working, flush iptables (they should be gone when stoping the firewall but it's worth giving a try):

```
iptables -F
```

Make sure there's nothing there:

```
iptables -L
```

Restart apache and check again.  Still not working? Then you made a mistake on your config file, so I would suggest openning another terminal with

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

(or wherever your error log is)

and restarting the service, you will probably see some errors there that may be causing the issue, for example, permissions or similar stuff.

Comment: Tanks you! After iptables -F everything is fine. Now i have to seriously study iptables

Comment: @Swalsz your welcome, make my answer the correct one so people can find it easily :)